# How to sanitize any integer input field in wordpress?

Tags: php, plugin-development

I would like to sanitize an input field of type integer WordPress. Like this..

```
<input type="number" name="amount" />
```

Now, what should I do?

Comment: Do you want to sanitize the input data in the frontend or backend, or both? What does this field do? did you make this form or does it come from a plugin?

Comment: I want to sanitize frontend (actually both) data. Lets say price field

Comment: Well a price field presumably has more requirements than a simple number. You can sanitize a positive integer with `absint()`, but for other types of numbers would would use core PHP functions. A price probably also requires a certain number of decimal places an potentially other things, so you would need to write your own function. So either way, this would be unrelated to WordPres.

Comment: I uploaded a plugin into the WordPress plugin store and they asked me to sanitize all the input fields. Well there is sanitize_text_field(). I understand that I need to use this function to sanitize the text input field. But what should I use a number type input field?

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that WordPress still does not provide a function to sanitize numbers. A common issue is that `(int)`, etc. simply truncate the input and fail if the input contains separators. Forcing a type on input like `4,000` produces `4` not `4000`, and [separators are different depending on the locale](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html).

There is [`NumberFormatter::parse()`](https://www.php.net/manual/numberformatter.parse.php), which is quite strict:

```php
$nf = new NumberFormatter('en_CA', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
var_dump($nf->parse('4 500,9', NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT64));
var_dump($nf->parse('4 5002,9', NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT64));
```

Output:

```
int(4500)
bool(false)
```

It also truncates numbers, and fails if input is not exactly the right format.

Alternatively, input can be parsed assuming anything that isn't an Arabic numeral (0-9), or the locale's decimal point, is irrelevant:

```php
# get the expected decimal point character for the current locale
$radix = nl_langinfo(DECIMAL_POINT);
# fall back to "." if locale function failed, and escape it for use in PCRE
$radix = preg_quote($radix === false ? '.' : $radix, '/');
# scrub out anything that's not a digit or the decimal point
$parsed = preg_replace("/[^\d$radix]+/", '', $input);
# get number parts and tolerate repeated decimal points
$parsed = preg_split("/$radix+/", $parsed);
# either truncate any fraction...
$parsed_truncated = (int) $parsed[0];
# or round it
$parsed_rounded = (int) round($parsed[0] . '.' . ($parsed[1] ?? '0'), 0);
```

The rounded output will be `1010` from input like  `10,0 9. 7`. It doesn't handle negative numbers, but they could be detected by first searching the input for the presence of the character returned by `nl_langinfo(NEGATIVE_SIGN)`.